# Required WAL settings to permit large queries to run on server which is replicating to standby server

Tags: postgresql, configuration, write-ahead-logging

What WAL/conf settings are required to permit large queries in PostgreSQL without breaking replication to the replica server?

Is it only a matter of ensuring that:

- the WAL writes don't time out?
- the disk doesn't run out of space?
- the checkpoints don't timeout

Comment: Large *queries* (e.g. not DDL or DML) should not be breaking replication in the first place.  Is this a theoretical question, or is replication actually failing?  If the latter, what is the error message?